# How to let my twitter authenticated users automatically follow my twitter account on login

Tags: node.js, twitter

I want to add an option to allow the user to automatically follow me on my twitter account during twitter login

Comment: Please show what you have tried, some code that you already have, and where you are stuck solving this issue. Nobody will write that much code from scratch for you. Best regards.

Comment: I just wanted the link for the documentation. I have successfully authenticated the user using passport-twitter nodejs module . Now I just want to know the method to automatically let this user follow my twitter account.

Comment: Please keep in mind that such questions are off-topic at SO (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)